# Can a frozen chatroom be thawed?

Tags: discussion, chat

Once a chat rook is frozen, is there a way to get it to be active again? or is that room locked for ever and ever and ever?

Comment: Answer below is correct. At least one of your favorite mods can always be found in the farm or lurking around the site, feel free to ping!

Comment: Plus we are notified of every meta question, so asking here works too :)

Comment: All mods (from any site) carry a bottle of anti-freeze. Frozen chat rooms aren't a big deal. Like spring comes after every winter, frozen chat rooms are easily thawed. Just ping any diamond wielding user. (ok so maybe I added a comment just to keep the whole MOD squad together.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a moderator can unfreeze a frozen chatroom, so you'll have to ask them. One way to contact a moderator is to use a custom flag for moderator attention on some post (yours, for example). Or you could use this meta post you already created, adding a specific unfreezing request to ti.